# PHP Prepared statement ORDER BY column name

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have problems with ordering some content that I print by use of ORDER BY in prepared statement, since it's a column, I guess I have to use `?` instead of writing what I want to order by, but even though I try and change that, something goes wrong because it doesn't order correctly. I think my syntax might be wrong, how would you suggest or advice me to do it? Heres the code:

```
$n = 0;
$item_number = 0;
//Array which iterates over all objects in a given users object_id
$ref[$n];
$rowsize = 12;

for ($i = 0; $i < $rowsize; $i++) {

    $stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
    $stmt->prepare('SELECT z, name FROM house_room1 INNER JOIN objects ON house_room1.object_id=objects.object_id WHERE house_room1.ref_id = ? ORDER BY z'); 
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $i
    );
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $stmt->bind_result($z, $name);
        while($stmt->fetch()) {
            echo '<li id="item-' . $item_number . '" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>' . $name . '</li>'; 
            }
        }
     else {
        echo 'Something went terribly wrong' . $mysqli->error;
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $n++;
    $item_number++;
}
```

EDIT: uhh I don't know whats with the indent.. Btw it shall order by the column "z"

EDIT2: I want to see all the names in the database ordered by the z value that it has, so if the value is 0, the name with a z value of 0 should be shown first. the z values in the database are from 0 to 12. and it is connected to another table which has the name for that specific object with that specific z value.

Currently nothing happens no matter what I change the ORDER BY to, the things get spit out ordered by object_id instead of z, weirdly enough.

Comment: SQL code looks fine to me; `ORDER BY z` is the correct syntax.

Comment: Thanks Phil, for changing the indent, how did you do that? oh that is weird

Comment: I didn't but you can click the [edited ... ago](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22184821/revisions) link to see revisions

Comment: Try adding ASC or DESC... ORDER BY z ASC.

Comment: Jonathan weird thing is that no matter if I add DESC or ASC, no change, it should at least do the opposite.

Comment: Can you describe the actual problem you're having? Any error messages? What do you expect to see and what are you actually seeing?

Comment: what is the datatype of this column ant what values do you store in it? If it is `varchar` and you have numbers in it, it wont sort properly.

Comment: I made an edit to my post explaining some more, the value z is type int which should work I suppose.

Comment: So, you are creating 12 queries instead of 1? That would throw the total order out of whack of course. You are now sorting by `house_room1.ref_id` first (per query), then by `z` (in the query itself). Make it _one_ query.

Comment: @Wrikken I thought that might be the problem, but I am not quite sure how to change that and get the same function out of it. Thanks

Comment: Why is running a query like `WHERE house_room1.ref_id IN(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12) ORDER BY z` not an option?

Comment: uhm maybe it is? Besides that the number can increase, but I guess you could just increase that number by the row size of the database